# to_char on a date field giving unexpected results

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Looking at the two statements below can anyone tell me why I am getting "11:07" for the time from the second statement. I am expecting "11:00 PM" for the time given that the first statement returns 23:00.

```
 select early_shpdte
   from shipment
  where ship_id = '3644783_02_94874_5835330-01'
```

Result:  07-09-2019 23:00:00

```
 select to_char(early_shpdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM')
   from shipment
  where ship_id = '3644783_02_94874_5835330-01'
```

Result:  07/09/2019 11:07 PM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `MM` twice, so the 'minute' value in the time part is actually the month number. You want:

```
select to_char(early_shpdte, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')
--------------------------------------------^^
  from shipment
 where ship_id = '3644783_02_94874_5835330-01'
```

The format model elements are [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A).